# while + foreach подвешивает Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть вот такой кусок кода

```
while (key == KeyCode.None)
{
    foreach (ControllerPollingInfo info in ReInput.controllers.Keyboard.PollForAllKeys())
    {
        key = info.keyboardKey;
    }
}
```

Подвешивает при запуске Юнити насмерть. Он собирает данные по нажатым клавишам, и, видимо, делает это слишком быстро.

Очевидные решения которые пришли в голову мне -

1)вынести этот кусок кода в отдельный метод и вызывать в Update - вроде должно меньше виснуть.
2)Добавить корутину с, допустим,

```
yield return new WaitFoSeconds 0.25f,
```

4 опроса в секунду должно хватить для корректного опроса клавиатуры и не должно сильно подвешивать.

Есть у кого нибудь более простые и изящные решения?

Comment: отдельный поток ?

Comment: ваш кусок черезчур странный..... внутри цикла делаете еще цикл, в котором переменной `key` присваивается всегда только последнее значение из коллекции. Нафиг этот цикл еще один — непонятно. Что там внутри `ReInput.controllers.Keyboard.PollForAllKeys()` — непонятно. Что вообще этим хотите добиться — непонятно. Что там за пределами этого куска кода (может проблема именно не в данном куске) — непонятно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Это ассет Rewired. 
Он собирает инфу с клавиатуры и выдает её по условиям. Переделать его нельзя, поэтому и что там внутри - не имеет в данном случае значения. 

Понятно что операция опроса клавиатуры ресурсозатратна, но какой из этого выход? Только корутиной?

Comment: @Dmitrii переделывать не надо. вот скажите зачем вы обходите все значения в цикле, если в `key` попадает лишь последнее? В чем смысл?

Comment: @Dmitrii есть у меня подозрения, что уходит код вашей программы в бесконечный цикл... поэтому и зависает наглухо. Скорее всего проблема в том, что key никогда не равен KeyCode.None. Попробуйте от этого оттолкнуться. Добавьте внутри foreach вывод на консоль key, и посмотрите, работает ли ваш код так как вы хотите.

Comment: Конечно завесит. Вы запустили холостой цикл.

Comment: Запихните вместо `KeyCone.None` `!Input.anyKey`.Условие будет верно если никакая клавиша не нажата.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убери while. Если нужна проверка key - сделай её после или внутри foreach